# UITableViewCell nil condition

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Usually we configure the Cell outside the condition of Cell nil. In my case I am doing the same that convert NSData to image outside Cell nil. So that, every time I fire the request and reload table, It will convert data to image for particular cell perfectly. But after reloading table, my problem is that when I scroll the table, Every time it will convert NSData to image which is obvious. I need to avoid this conversion on scrolling after reloading table.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifierImage =  @"CellIdentifierImage";
if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NewsImageCell *newsImageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];

        if (newsImageCell == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"CellNil");
            newsImageCell = [[NewsImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];
            newsImageCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        if([[ApplicationData sharedInstance].arrTop10NewsHome count]>0)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dicSource = [arrSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSURL *urlImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[dicSource retrieveForPath:@"ItemImage"]];
            newsImageCell.lblNewsHeading.text = [dicSource objectForKey:@"Title"];
            [newsImageCell.loadingIndicator startAnimating];
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage]];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    newsImageCell.imgVwNews.image = image;
                    [newsImageCell.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
                });
            });
        }

        return newsImageCell;
    }
```

Appreciate your ideas
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

use [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) instead of UIImageView.

see the demo project of [EgoImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

Answer (score 0):

You may use HJCache https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache
Which may best suit for this situation.